# java mysql server getting slower

Tags: java, mysql, performance

I manage my connections by JDBC connection pool (BoneCP) and I always close the connection, the preparedStatement und the ResultSet.

But, when my programm is running for several days, the mysql-server gets slower and slower (for testing, I let my programm insert an entry every second). After 2 days, there were several seconds between the entries and that is why I think that the mysql server is getting slower and can handle the incomming transaction. **Am I right?**

The mysql server also uses much more of RAM and does not release the resources. **So does anyone know, how I could find the error causing this behaviour?** Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) to detect open connections. It also gives you a host of options to see performance of your database server.

Also [I might be mistaken about this part of your question], when you say

> I use connection pooling

why do you close the connection? Isn't that the opposite of the purpose of connection pooling?

Comment: You don't really close the connection, when you use a connection pool - the function close() gets a whole new meaning, where the connection is not physically closed, but just released for further use.
Thanks for suggesting to use workbench - I will try to debug with this tool :)